# How to copy/paste text from browser / Wikipedia HTML table and save it as HTML in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, clipboard, copy-paste

I know the clipboard must have an HTML copy of the copied text (CMD+C), because when I copy an HTML table from Wikipedia like [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_script#Punctuation_marks), it pastes in the spreadsheet (CMD+V) as if it knew about the HTML data:

[image]

How do I do that same thing that Google Sheets is doing, but in VSCode? That is, I want to paste the raw HTML I copied into VSCode, how can I do that? I guess I can right-click inspect element and copy outer HTML, but is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=d3v.pastespecial

---

**Longer answer:**

Correct, the clipboard stores multiple formats of copied data, e.g. plain text and HTML as you have demonstrated with your Google sheets example.

Within a browser context, you can use the [Clipbopard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) to access this data, but due to security reasons, this needs to be triggered by a user action.

This demo will work in Chrome over a secure connection:

```
document.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    for (const clipboardItem of clipboardItems) {
      for (const type of clipboardItem.types) {
        if (type === 'text/html') {
          const blob = await clipboardItem.getType(type);
          const text = await new Response(blob).text();
          console.log('HTML content from clipboard:', text);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to read clipboard:', err);
  }
});
```

When pasting into VSCode, regardless of what is on the clipboard, it will always paste plain text.

There is an issue discussing this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57577

As one can see from the last comment, the current suggestion for implementing the ability to paste HTML directly, is to use the following extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=d3v.pastespecial

After installing the extension, copy some text to your clipboard from your web browser, then in VS Code hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and select *HTML Source* and the HTML will be pasted into the editor.

I just tried it out and it works fine on Linux. The extension page says that it also supports Windows, but it looks like macOS support is limited.

---

**Edit**: shoot! looks like you are on a mac. I guess this won't work then, in which case right-click inspect element and copy outer HTML is (sadly) the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In vscode, as of Stable v1.86 early February 2023 there are two ways to `paste as html`.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57577#issuecomment-1904917670

> This feature is now in VS code insiders. While I initially enabled it
> by default, it is now opt-in and will not show up normally. This is
> because we found it was showing up far too often
>
> There are two ways to trigger it when there is text/html content in
> the clipboard:
>
> - Use the `Paste as...` command
> - Setup a custom keybinding with "id": "html":
>
> ```json
> {     
>   "key": "cmd+k x",   
>   "command": "editor.action.pasteAs",
>   "when": "editorTextFocus",  
>   "args": {       
>     "id": "html"  
>    } 
> }
> ```